# Как почистить папку upload с помощью SSH

Tags: битрикс, ssh

Постоянно засоряется папка upload, из за этого сайт весит в 2 3 раза больше, я слышал что можно как то почистить кешированные файлы и весь этот мусор с помощью SSH консоли. CMS BITRIX

Comment: А просто в шедулер положить команду очистки папки от файлов старше заданного срока?

Comment: @Akina можно пожалуйста подробнее как это сделать ?

Comment: Что вызывает сложности? Создание задания (скажем, ежесуточного) в CRON, или формирование команды на удаление файлов по дате сколько-то дней минус по сравнению с текущей?

Comment: @Akina у меня сайт весит 7Гб а кеш на 12ГБ , нужно исправить эту проблему )

Comment: Это мы уже поняли.

Comment: @Akina я просто никогда не пользовался этим , только слышал что через SSH можно сделать все окей, сейчас гуглю по этому поводу еще. Просто хотел спросить , если кто- то знает , смог бы помочь

Comment: SSH - всего лишь шифрованный канал соединения, после установления связи всё выполняется так, как будто у тебя обычное нешифрованное подключение.

Comment: @Akina 
Нашел что - то вроде этого:
umask(000);
@umask(~BX_DIR_PERMISSIONS);

Пишут надо добавить этот "скрипт"  в /bitrix/php_interface/dbconn.php

Comment: Кеш вы можете удалить и через админку.

Comment: @Nikolaj_Sarry Да все верно ,  удалил через админку , просто видимо он это делает не моментально и сразу не показало очистку .После удаления кеша мне выдало инфу , что-то вроде , очистка кеша произошла успешно на 500 мб, но удалило 12ГБ

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Mediahero/bitrix-clear-upload

Скрипт для очистки каталога upload/iblock сайта на CMS 1С-Битрикс от неиспользуемых файлов (оставшихся после удаления элемента инфоблока).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm path_to_upload/* -rf
```

Выполните это в консоли, указав полный путь до вашей директории upload